# Multiple buttons same functions assign value to different textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Here's what I'm trying to do, I have 2 buttons & 2 fields. Those 2 buttons have the same selector but with different data- attribute. I wanted that when clicking one of those buttons, it'll get the value and add it to their designated textfield. My current code only works on the first field I clicked and after that, if I clicked on my second button it will not assign the value on the second field, it will assign the value on whichever button I selected first.

and here are my fields:

**1st button & its designated textfield:**

**2nd button & its designated textfield:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var mediaUploader;
  $('.upload_image_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonID = $(this).data('group');
    if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
        text: 'Choose Image'
      },
      multiple: false
    });
    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      $('#upload_image_' + buttonID).val(attachment.url);
    });
    mediaUploader.open();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upload_image_1" type="text" name="upload_image_1" value="<?php echo get_option('upload_image_1'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="1" />
<input id="upload_image_2" type="text" name="upload_image_2" value="<?php echo get_option('upload_image_1'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="2" />
```

Comment: ids must be unique and you have `id="upload_image_button"` on both buttons

Comment: Including php echo statements in your code here doesn't help, you can literally echo anything there. What's the rendered html code instead?

Comment: Im using class as selector for the buttons. Here's the rendered html fields & buttons:   <input id="upload_image_1" type="text" name="upload_image_1" value="" class="regular-text"> <input type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="1">
  <input id="upload_image_2" type="text" name="upload_image_2" value="" class="regular-text"> <input type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="2">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to unbind the `select` event before `return;`, @JasonB's suggestion feels valid too. I attempted to create an example but I don't know if it would be helpful:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var mediaUploader;
  var buttonID;
  $('.upload_image_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonID = $(this).data('group');
    if (mediaUploader) {
      $("select").unbind('change');
      console.log('open media');
      //return;
    }
    mediaUploader = 1;
    /*wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
          title: 'Choose Image',
          button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
          },
          multiple: false
        });
        mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
          var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
          */
    $("select").on('change', function() {
      $('#upload_image_' + buttonID).val('value');
      alert();
    });
    /*
        });
        mediaUploader.open();*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upload_image_1" type="text" name="upload_image_1" value="" class="regular-text">
<input type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="1">
<input id="upload_image_2" type="text" name="upload_image_2" value="" class="regular-text">
<input type="button" class="upload_image_button button-primary" value="Insert Image" data-group="2">
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has an if statement that is intended to prevent reinitialization of the media uploader.

```
if (mediaUploader) {
  mediaUploader.open();
  return;
}
mediaUploader = ...
```

Remove this code so your mediaUploader is recreated every time you click on a button instead of reusing the stored one with the initial values.